# MyDSL code Validation is not working when cleaning the project

Tags: java, dsl, xtext, xtend, mwe

In my DSL validator code, it's not working when i clean the project or when i change in one file. 
Then i used google, came to know like have to register EPackage in Evalidator but in my ecore model don't have like that.

So please let me know the answer for this..

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use an imported or a generated EPackage? Are you sure that your validator is really instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

My Problem has been resolved by binding the resource in SharedRuntimeModule of the DSL language.